# Protecting the Specific Shapes and Images in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Sheet with some macros. Also, I have some navigation shapes and images on my sheet. I want users of this sheet, cannot change this shapes and images positions, can't select them and can't move them.

Is there any way to Protect some specific objects?

Regards.

Comment: You might hard-program the properties you don't want to be changed and run an event procedure on Worksheet_Activate to move everything back to where it belongs.

Comment: If you use the Active-X controls instead of shapes or form controls, then in design mode you can right-click, select Format Control > Properties > and tick "Don't Move or SIze with Cells".

Comment: it is useful in circumstances like this, if going with Variatus's suggestion, to have some boilerplate code that loops objects in sheets (e.g. OLEObjects and writes out their position information e.g. to a text file. Makes hard coding specific positions a lot quicker.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an age old question ever since Shapes were added to MS Excel and the answer to which I myself was looking for many years already.
I just found out 3 days ago, on my own, how to lock MS Excel Freeform shapes like Choropleth Map shapes from being moved around, reformatted or worst, deleted, all WITHOUT needing to lock the WorkSheet, or eventually the WorkBook.
And I think I must share my discovery with the world because everyone wants to lock their Shapes!

Steps: (I work with Excel VBA and with msoFreeform shapes mostly but I think any shape should be working and manually added shapes through Excel UI should work too and in other Office Apps as well)

1.(yourWorkSheet or )ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart (through VBA but MAYBE you can add chart through Excel UI and then delete the only chart)
 (no need for any other parameter because we just need the chart container, "ChartObject")

2.If you don't have some already, create a shape either through Excel UI or through VBA with AddShape method or BuildFreeform on the Chart directly or on to the worksheet.

3.Copy/Paste the created shape (if created through Excel UI or through VBA on the worksheet) on to the BLANK Chart Container. (NOT drag and drop)

4.Format the ChartContainer Rectangle window as required (try "No Fill & No Outline") through VBA or Excel UI

5.There are 3 options regarding protection of a Chart 
(Embedded chart here because I don't work with Chart Sheets, may be this might work with them)
source:[https://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ChartProtection.html]
But here, only the relevant 2 will be shown:

5(a)ActiveChart.ProtectFormatting = True
That protection will block any formatting changes on the Shape and the Chart via "Chart Tools Menu" or "Drawing Tools - Format Menu" or moving or resizing with mouse or deleting BUT will show the ChartContainer window upon Selection via Mouse but non-selectable via VBA
eg. `yourworksheet.ChartObjects("YourChartName").Chart.ProtectFormatting=True`

5(b)ActiveChart.ProtectSelection = True
That will stop the shape or the chart from being selected altogether so this is the end of story
eg. `yourworksheet.ChartObjects("YourChartName").Chart.ProtectSelection=True`

The best thing about this method is that the shape can still be accessible through VBA like 
eg.`yourworksheet.ChartObjects("YourChartName").Chart.Shapes("YourShapeName or Index").whatever`
except Shape.Select which should be obvious and there is NO need to lock the Worksheet or Workbook at all.

NB:1)The interesting finding here is that the 2 protections do not replace each other (if applied one after another) but more like stacked with each other meaning if both (if you really want) were set True first and then after setting  either one False, the other restriction still remains.

2)Even if selection is protected as above, the chart can still be accessible through the Selection Pane, therefore: 
`Application.CommandBars("Selection and Visibility").Enabled = False` 
and also blocking the Worksheet Export are advisable but I think these are overkill nonetheless included for completeness' sake.

Discovered and tested on MS Excel 2010 so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Nay Lynn's answer caused my Excel to crash.  Specifically with the `.ProtectSelection` property being enabled (using `Microsoft365 Excel`). . .  Excel VBA's `Intellisense` *shows* the property, so it is legitimate, but everything would be fine until the chart was selected.  Playing around with this idea though, I did find a great work around.

```
 1. Place a Chart on your sheet.  Make it span across the area you want to protect
(we will expand the size of this chart later).
    a. Leave Fill of Chart at Default until a later step (this helps ensure the
next steps are successful).
    b. Delete all the elements present for the chart (Series label, Title, Etc.)
    c. Shrink the "Plot Area" box leftover to as negligible as possible.
    d.  CRITICAL:  Right Click the chart and choose "Select Data" - use the
option to remove all the data in the boxes of this dialog, otherwise when
you select the Rectangle added below, it will show the data references as
selections in the Worksheet behind it.

 2. Insert a Rectangle into the Chart.  It will have the default colors.

 3. Tap `Esc` to clear the selection.  If you select the shape and try to move it
around, it will take precedence over the Chart itself (this is how we'll trick
Excel later).
    a. Confirm this does not allow the shape to be pulled beyond the border of the
Chart.

 4. Set Fill of Chart to be "No Fill"

 5. Expand the Rectangle's size to match the size of the chart.

 6. Set Fill of Rectangle to be a color with 100% Transparency (NOT the same as "No
Fill" - this is critical)
    a. You should be able to see all of your shapes, etc, but not touch them if you
click where the rectangle was, and trying to click and drag will also fail since the 
Rectangle takes selection precedence and is also bound by the chart.

 7. Set the fill of the Rectangle back to a color with 0 transparency (we need to
find the edge of the shape)

 8. Select the Rectangle's border and it should then select the Chart instead (you
should see the chart Format option appear).

 9. Expand the Chart's border to the ends of the Excel Sheet (ensure the top left
corner sits in the top left corner of the sheet by dragging it).  You can also set
the height/width to an absurd number that users will get fed up with trying to find
if you do not wish to expand it across the entire boundaries (or if there's a hard
limitation - I did not try to expand across the entire sheet, but went to "BO400"
with no issue.
    a. Expand the Rectangle to fit the Chart once again if it did not expand
automatically (in my case it did, but I cannot guarantee this behavior)
    b. If you have any Buttons that DO need to be clicked, place this chart
at the bottom, place all the buttons/shapes etc. that need interaction to
the top, then bring the chart up a level until all the items needing
protection are hidden.
    c. Change the Transparency back to 100%

 10. After you have the Chart expanded properly, you will need to use a bit of VBA
to ensure the Chart's Formatting is protected as Nay Lynn mentions.  Get the 
Chart's name by selecting the border, and institute some VBA Code that gets
toggled based on your needs (you might want to include an unprotect sub
as well just in case).
```

```
  Example:

      Sub Protect_Sheet_With_Chart ()
        dim sht as Worksheet
        dim chrt as Chart
        Set sht = ActiveSheet
          'You can use a sheet by name for the above as well - make your code robust.
        Set chrt = sht.ChartObjects("ChartNameFoundFromStep10").Chart
        chrt.ProtectFormatting = True
      End Sub

      Sub UnProtect_Sheet_With_Chart ()
        dim sht as Worksheet
        dim chrt as Chart
        Set sht = ActiveSheet
          'You can use a sheet by name for the above as well - make your code robust.
        Set chrt = sht.ChartObjects("ChartNameFoundFromStep10").Chart
        chrt.ProtectFormatting = False
      End Sub
```

```
 11. After you protect the Chart, selecting it and deleting will not
actually delete it, NOR the rectangle, so it can't be removed!

 12. Protect your code somehow and you'll be set!
```